# Woocommerce variation pricing table

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason when the price of the attributes is the same, it does not show the price in the table.

Can anyone assist me to spot what the issue might be?

```
if($product->is_type('variable')){
    echo '<tr><td class="desc">Serving Size</td><td class="desc">Price</td></tr>';

    foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ){
        // Attributes
        $attributes = array();
        foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
            $taxonomy = str_replace('attribute_', '', $key );
            // $taxonomy_label = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;
            $term_name = get_term_by( 'slug', $value, $taxonomy )->name;
            $attributes[] = $taxonomy_label.''.$term_name;
        }
        echo '<tr><td>'.implode( ' | ', $attributes ).'</td>';

        // Prices
        $active_price = floatval($variation['display_price']); // Active price
        $regular_price = floatval($variation['display_regular_price']); // Regular Price
        if( $active_price != $regular_price ){
            $sale_price = $active_price; // Sale Price
        }
        echo '<td>'.$variation['price_html'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
else {
    echo '<tr><td class="desc">Price</td></tr>
    <tr><td>'.$product->get_price_html().'</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: Any URL or screenshot would help. Please provide if you are comfortable.

Comment: sure thing :) https://dev.jaffedigital.com.au/cosma/product/borekas/

Comment: Thank you, in fact your variable is empty. Or in your Variations, filled field has some other name. Please provide a screenshot of variations table from edit product page where I can see the prices field, either it is regular price or sale price or maybe an empty field.

Comment: It seems to work in all other variable products, except when the price is the same in both variations. For example, if I make it 4.95 and 4.96 it works.. so strange.

Comment: Still I will ask you to check $variation['price_html'] because maybe it is empty.